# Email Trigger In sitecore CDP

Tags: cdp

In sitecore CDP ,I have created connection for send email. this connection is triggerd but status is error. can anyone suggest me the way to run this email trigger successfully?
[image]

My request is

```
{
  "Messages": [
    {
      "From": {
        "Email": "mymail@gmail.com",
        "Name": "mymail"
      },
      "To": [
        {
          "Email": "mymail@gmail.com",
          "Name": "mymail"
        }
      ],
      "Subject": "My first Mailjet Email!",
      "TextPart": "Greetings from Mailjet!",
      "HTMLPart": "<h3>Dear passenger 1, welcome to <a href=\"https://www.mailjet.com/\">Mailjet</a>!</h3><br />May the delivery force be with you!"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my response of this email trigger

```
"responsePayload": {
      "headers": "null",
      "body": "{\"body\":\"{\\n  \\\"statusCode\\\" : 400,\\n  \\\"reason\\\" : \\\"Bad Request\\\",\\n  \\\"responseBody\\\" : {\\n    \\\"ErrorIdentifier\\\" : \\\"f36854a5-0199-40c8-945b-dda96dd9c3fd\\\",\\n    \\\"ErrorCode\\\" : \\\"mj-0003\\\",\\n    \\\"StatusCode\\\" : 400,\\n    \\\"ErrorMessage\\\" : \\\"Missing mandatory property.\\\",\\n    \\\"ErrorRelatedTo\\\" : [ \\\"Messages\\\" ]\\n  },\\n  \\\"url\\\" : \\\"https://api.mailjet.com/v3.1/send\\\"\\n}\"}",
      "statusCode": null
    },
    "statusCode": 400,
    "errorData": "{\n  \"statusCode\" : 400,\n  \"reason\" : \"Bad Request\",\n  \"responseBody\" : {\n    \"ErrorIdentifier\" : \"f36854a5-0199-40c8-945b-dda96dd9c3fd\",\n    \"ErrorCode\" : \"mj-0003\",\n    \"StatusCode\" : 400,\n    \"ErrorMessage\" : \"Missing mandatory property.\",\n    \"ErrorRelatedTo\" : [ \"Messages\" ]\n  },\n  \"url\" : \"https://api.mailjet.com/v3.1/send\"\n}",
    "executionTimeMs": 104,
    "connectionUrl": "https://api.mailjet.com/v3.1/send",
    "mappingResult": null
```

Comment: Could you provide error details from Experience Execution (when you click "View Experience Execution")?

Comment: Hi @x3mxray ,Thankyou for your response .I have added the error response in question .please check it.

Comment: I found your experience in Partner Sandbox, and as I see you have incorrect syntax in API response in Freemarker (in line 3 you have "{  <#-- Freemarker will go here -->   }" that duplicates "{..}"). So just delete line 3 and leave only "{  "Messages": [...] }".

Comment: hi @x3mxray, I have mentioned my request in the question. when I try to test the request  from the connection, the test result is "statuscode:200".but when I try to run this with the experience it failed to trigger.as per your response in the comment ,exactly in which place I need to remove this "{}".

Comment: see an image in aswer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your experience in **Partner Sandbox**, and as I see you have incorrect syntax in API response in *Freemarker* (in line 3 you have "{ <#-- Freemarker will go here --> }" that duplicates "{..}"). So just delete line 3:

```
1. <#-- Construct the API response using Freemarker -->
2. <#-- For your Experience to run your API tab must have, at a minimum, open and closing brackets -->
3. {  <#-- Freemarker will go here -->   } // DELETE this line
4.
5.{
6.      "Messages":[
7.              {
8.                      "From": {
9.                              "Email": "usertrialsignup@gmail.com",
10.                             "Name": "Test user"
11.                     },
12.                     "To": [
13.                             {
14.                                     "Email": "usertrialsignup@gmail.com",
15.                                     "Name": "test receiver"
16.                             }
17.                     ],
18.                     "Subject": "My first Mailjet Email!",
19.                     "TextPart": "Greetings from Mailjet!",
20.                     "HTMLPart": "<h3>Dear passenger 1, welcome to <a href=\"https://www.mailjet.com/\">Mailjet</a>!</h3><br />May the delivery force be with you!"
21.             }
22.     ]
23.     }
```

[image]